# How to install logging module?

Tags: python, logging, installation, module, pip

I got this error while using 'pip install logging':

```
> pip install logging
Collecting logging
  Using cached logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz (96 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\_virtualenv.py", line 89, in exec_module
          old(module)
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 32, in <module>
          from setuptools.extern.more_itertools import unique_everseen
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 52, in create_module
          return self.load_module(spec.name)
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 37, in load_module
          __import__(extant)
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\more_itertools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
          from .more import *  # noqa
        File "c:\users\asr\pycharmprojects\groupmanagerbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\more_itertools\more.py", line 5, in <module>
          from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
        File "C:\Users\Asr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
        File "C:\Users\Asr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
          import logging
        File "C:\Users\Asr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e8vt44bg\logging_ae969009ecd74e96b07ddaa395b71854\logging\__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Then what does the error says when you install logging?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `pip install logging` - the `logging` package is now part of the Python standard library. The `logging` package on `pip` is old and hasn't been used or updated for many years.